# Managing privileges for an ArcSDE database using SSMS

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to mange users for my ArcSDE database via SSMS as opposed to tools in ArcGIS, to do this i want to set up two new user roles, data-viewer and data-editor, and then assign users to those roles. However, while i have been able to create new roles and add users to those roles i can not figure out how to configure the permissions in SQL to accomplish what i am trying to do.

So how do i configure the permissions in SSMS to create a data-viewer and data-editor role for my database

So far this what i have..

Query 1:
Create Role [data_editor] Authorization [dbo]

Query 2:
Alter Role [data_editor] ADD Member [AD\xxxxx]

Query 3:
Grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 'on all existing an future datasets' To [data_editor]

yeah the third query is where it falls apart because i dont know how to set it up so the role can do what is needed...

although according to ESRI i can not do what i want and the only way is  to create a user in the database server side and then mange the privilege to the datasets in Arc

Comment: It would probably help to **edit** the question to include the SQL you've written so far.

Comment: Pretty simple breakdown on the [Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002q0000002s000000).

Comment: @evv_gis that is helpfull however i still run in  the fact that i dont know how to format the sql syntax to write a query to do that or how to use SSMS to apply the permissions. i might just have to come back to it after i take some classes.

Comment: The "on all existing *and future* datasets" part is what makes this impossible.